# R - Force default plot function to be scatterplot

Tags: r, logistic-regression, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a dataset with a 2 level factor on the y axis and a numerical variable on the x axis in order to draw a logistic regression.  However when I try to create a plot I get a bar graph instead of a scatterplot.  Is there a way to force R to plot this as a scatterplot?

I've tried other scatterplot methods (ggplot2, scatterplot from car) but I'm also having issues getting them to draw the logistic curve, hence I'm trying to make the default plotting work.

Code for plot -

```
plot(Threatened~tl_mm.log, data=df2)
```

Structure of the relevant variables

```
str(df2)
$ Threatened     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Not_Threatened",..: 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
$ tl_mm.log      : num  3.48 3.54 3.57 3.28 3.54 ...
```

Comment: `plot(Threatened~ as.numeric(tl_mm.log), data=df2)`

Comment: Try: `plot(x=df2$tl_mm.log, y=df2$Threatened)`

Comment: Dang not sure why changing how the variables are referenced worked, but that worked!  Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Dave2e, see above comment -

```
plot(x=df2$tl_mm.log, y=df2$Threatened)
```